# Weird Behaviour with New Lines Using grunt-exec

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, gruntjs, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick and grunt-exec to generate a favicon for a website I am working on using the command found in the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon).

```
convert image.png  -bordercolor white -border 0 \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 \) \
      -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico
```

However I am getting some issues with line breaks which I think is partially because I do not fully understand what I should do with the line breaks.

In my `Gruntfile.js` I am currently using no line breaks and it works as expected. Notice that I had to remove all the line breaks and double escape the parentheses because apparently grunt-exec parses the string before it executes it.

```
exec: {
    favicon: 'convert _favicon.svg -bordercolor white -border 0 \\( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \\) \\( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \\) \\( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \\) \\( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 \\) -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico'
}
```

Like I said, I have it working right now but **I would like to be able to use line breaks for readability** and also because I would like to fully understand what is going on here. So far I have tried adding an extra `\` and leaving everything the same, replacing the new lines with `\n` or `\\n` and putting everything on the same line but no luck.

Comment: seems like you need to keep the dbl-escapes for the parens. Also, be sure that the ending '\' char on each line is the last character, NO trailing spaces or tabs. `cat -vet file` will show you `$` as the end of line. If you don't see '\$' on those lines, but '\^I   $' or similar, your editor is likely trying to be helpful and add spaces on lines to make navigation in the file easier (or other reasons). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was looking for turned out to be to use `\n\` for new lines, like this:

```
convert image.png  -bordercolor white -border 0 \n\
    \( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \) \n\
    \( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \) \n\
    \( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \) \n\
    \( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 \) \n\
    -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
exec: {
    favicon: 'convert _favicon.svg -bordercolor white -border 0 "( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 )" "( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 )" "( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 )" "( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 )" -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico'
}
```